# RxJS map function inside of merge function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to merge 3 different observables and identify them as source value. Also I am getting userDetails in withLatestfrom so that I can do operation depending on which observable got triggered (username - u, password - p, age - a). I am confident that there is something wrong in the fact that I am putting map functions inside of Observable.merge and that is why no matter which Observable was supposed to trigger my source is always 'u' in "switch case" statement.

```
@Effect
public test = Observable.merge(
  this.onUserNameUpdate().pipe(
    map(() => 'u')),
    this.onPasswordUpdate().pipe(
      map(() => 'p')), 
      this.onAgeUpdate().pipe(map(() => 'a')))
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getUserDetails),
      (source, userDetails) => ({
        source,
        order
      })
  )
  .map((params) => {
    switch (params.source) {
      case 'u':
        // do smth with username
      case 'p':
        // do smth with password
      case 'a':
        // do smth with age
    }
    return {
      // some object
    }
  })
```

Could anyone explain what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Rxjs are you using? Are you using `rxjs-compat` as well? I'm asking that coz you're using `Observable.merge` as well as `.pipe` which are syntaxes from two different versions of Rxjs.

Comment: I am using rxjs 5. I guess I am supposed to not use Observable.merge then?
I am not using rxjs-compat.

Comment: If you're using Rxjs5, then you should not be able to use `.pipe` I guess. Your operators(`map`) would directly chain to the Observable value itself.

Comment: Can you replicate this via a Minimal StackBlitz sample?

Comment: Strange, I thought it is other way around... Correct me if I am wrong.

https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44

Comment: merge is implemented as a static AND as an instance method. So you could use "Observable.merge(...)" (static) and ".pipe(merge(...))" (instance)

Comment: A i forgot: RxJs 5.0 does NOT support the "pipe" Operator. RxJS 5.5 and newer does support it. My comment before refere to RxJs 5.5 and newer.

Comment: Ahh yes, makes sense then. I am using rxjs 5.5.

Comment: you are subscribing to this chain, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace first mixed (`pipe` and observable operators) part with some pure RxJS 5 array of observables:

```
public test = Observable
.merge(
  this.onUserNameUpdate()
  .map(v => 'u'),
  this.onPasswordUpdate()
  .map(v => 'p'),
  this.onAgeUpdate()
  .map(v => 'a')
)
```

And see If your switch/case is moving accordingly.

As well I see you are getting additional user details depending on what source observable triggered action, I'd enclose this in `concatMap`:

```
.concatMap((trigger) => {
    return this.store.select(getUserDetails)
    .map(user => {
       let ret = user;
       ret.trigger = trigger;;
    })
})
```

In the end you got user info with metadata od what triggered change

### EDIT

As a result of above code your stream shall be something like this:
Each `onXXXUpdate` function that emits observable as a result is merged using `merge` operator:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-merge
Because merge operator returns single observable that is capable of emitting every value type that it's "child" observables are emitting, in next operator `concatMap` we map each value emitted (regardless of it's source) to new observable that is created as output from `this.store.select(getUserDetails)` (I assumed this function returns observable, isn't it?). To keep track of what is the trigger we append this information as meta-data into user info response via `map`. Afterwards, in final operator we shall have user info with trigger information that helps to distinguish, what actions shall be taken.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately, when I used array of observables they are not being triggered at all and it never reaches the switch case statement.

Comment: whoops, my bad, according to docs, this shall not be an array in static `merge`. I fixed my answer

Comment: Actually I managed to make it work with array as well. Apparently there is a workaround using the ... operator. 
Something like that: Observable.merge(...[this.onUserNameUpdate().map(() => 'u'), this.onPasswordUpdate().map(() => 'p'), this.onAgeUpdate().map(() => 'a')])

Unfortunately, I still have the same bug as in OP.

Comment: I tried your updated version even before I posted the question and it has the same problem as well. I am always getting the 'u' response.

Comment: have you tried to skip this `withLatestFrom` operator? And yes, `...` operator will convert array to it's entities, so probably rather than calling it a hack it's a syntactic sugar :)